# Windows Powershell $profile does not show a real path

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I launch Windows Powershell (by hitting the windows key, typing "powershell" and pressing enter which launches `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`) and type `$profile` and press enter and see `WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

As far as I know, this is not a valid path. I was hoping for something like `C:\Windows\...`

When I type `$profile | Format-List * -Force`, however, there is some progress and I get

```
AllUsersAllHosts       : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1
AllUsersCurrentHost    : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
CurrentUserAllHosts    : WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
CurrentUserCurrentHost : WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
Length                 : 50
```

However the `CurrentUserAllHosts` and `CurrentUserCurrentHosts` are still non-paths. What do these non-paths mean? Do they refer to some hidden values or do I need to set some system values somewhere?

Here is my `$PsVersionTable.PsVersion`

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14393  206
```

Here are the results of `Get-Host`

```
Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 5.1.14393.206
InstanceId       : a2a61a42-f2ee-46b9-b67a-ef441301bdb8
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
DebuggerEnabled  : True
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

Comment: Are you using some custom host? What output of this command `[Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::Personal)`?

Comment: Wouldn't PowerShell refuse to even start if that definition were missing?

Comment: It gives an empty response

Comment: For me, in a Win 10 machine, the value for $profile is `C:\Users\userNamexxx\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` However there is no such folder nor the file !

Comment: There isn't by default, you have to create it. @Mark, what happens if you run `[Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")` and open CMD and run `echo %USERPROFILE%`?

Comment: Could WindowsPowerShell probably refers to the installation location of powershell, based on 32 or 64 process being used ? From C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1, it looks more like it!

Comment: On Server-2016, `$Profile.CurrentUserAllHosts` => `C:\Users\ebelew\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1`, so this is likely a local thing.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks for accepting; can you tell us what the cause of the problem was in the end, perhaps as an addendum to your question?

Comment: Sorry I was not able to access my Windows computer for some time. However, when I tried it just now... the path was fine! I feel like the problem may have been that I changed my home folder from `C:\Users\marki` to `C:\Users\mark` and then Windows got confused somehow. Now that I have it back to the default `marki` maybe it got fixed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<sup>**Note**: This question is *not* about the `$PROFILE` file simply *not existing*, possibly along with *its directory*. If `$PROFILE` shows the expected path and you simply want to ensure that the file exists, use

`if (-not (Test-Path $PROFILE)) { $null = New-Item -Force $PROFILE }`</sup>

**tl;dr**:

The **problem** may not be PowerShell-related, but **may be due to a missing special-folder path definition in the *registry***.

Verify that registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders` contains a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` value named `Personal` with data `%USERPROFILE%\Documents` - see diagnostic commands below.

If you find that you must (re)create it, use:

```
New-ItemProperty `
  'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders' `
  Personal -Value '%USERPROFILE%\Documents' -Type ExpandString -Force
```

and then log off and back on (or reboot) to see if that fixed the problem.

---

[Eris's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42331551/45375) tells us that the ***user-specific* PS profile paths are derived from what `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)` returns**.

.NET gets this value, presumably via the [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Shell API function, from registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`, value `Personal`, where it is normally defined as a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` value containing (expandable) string `%USERPROFILE%\Documents`.
(There's also a legacy fallback location - see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962613.aspx).)

Profiles `CurrentUserAllHosts` and `CurrentUserCurrentHost` containing just *relative* paths, namely:

- `WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1`
- `WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

suggests that **the `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)` call, whose result is used as the path *prefix*, unexpectedly returned an *empty string*, which in turn suggests a *registry  problem*.**

---

Here are some **diagnostic commands** and their expected outputs (`jdoe` represents your username):

```
# Verify that %USERPROFILE% is defined.
> $env:USERPROFILE
C:\Users\jdoe

# Verify that %USERPROFILE% is defined in the registry.
> Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKCU:\Volatile Environment' USERPROFILE
C:\Users\jdoe

# Verify that the API call to retrieve the known folder
# "Personal" (Documents) returns the expected value.
> [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Personal')
C:\Users\jdoe\Documents

# See if the registry contains the expected definition.
> Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders' Personal
C:\Users\jdoe\Documents
```

Answer (score 8):

According to the powershell source code on github, they look for `Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal`

It starts in [ConsoleHost.cs](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ConsoleHost.cs#L1760)
and you can track this down to [utils.cs](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/Utils.cs#L292) where they call `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today and I was able to create the profile with the following PowerShell command:

```
New-Item -path $PROFILE -type File -force
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Note that yours was a _different_ issue: The value of your `$PROFILE` variable was correct (unlike in the OP's case), but the file pointed to - possibly along with its parent directory - simply _didn't exist yet_. This is what `New-Item -Force` addresses: it creates the file, including its directory, if needed. Note, however, that if the file _already exists_, you'll _wipe out its contents_. [GitHub issue #11677](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11677) asks for a new switch to be added to `New-Item` to allow preserving a preexisting file.